# Unit Testing - Workflow Field Update

Tags: unit-test, workflow

A SF newbie here.

Is it possible to write a test class that can check WF field updates also ?.

I have a WF update created on a Custom object CaseLog__c.

Is it possible for me to write a Apex Test case  to check whether the field update is happening as expected ?.

I know no code will be covered, but can I still a write unit test case and check whether it is working as expected ?.

Any input on it will be appreciated ..tx

Comment: yes. you can simply write a test for it and assert the results are as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. Just write a unit test that creates the CaseLog__c record, then sets whatever criteria are needed to fire off the workflow, then requery the record and do a system.assertEquals() to make sure that the record has the expected value.

You can also do this to check that formula fields, roll-up fields, and validation rules are working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely write that ,lets say in your case your workflow is updating a field name with 'abc' for CaseLog__c record ,simply write unit test as below

```
private static class unitTest{
   public static testmethod void unittestworkflow(){
      CaseLog__c c=new CaseLog__c();
      c.parentfield=parentfield;
      //....other mandatory fields here
      test.startTest();
      insert c;
      system.assert([Select name from caseLog__c where Id=:c.id].name=='abc');
      test.stoptest();
  }
}
```